# Magento template changes not showing

Tags: magento, nginx

I am trying to edit content of Contact us page in Magento.

\\"app/design/frontend/enterprise/mytheme/template/contactus/contactus.phtml\\"

I cleared cache, but change not showing on front end. I deleted files in /var/cache, but no luck. The magento site is in nginx. Please let me know if there is anything else other than cache to view changes in magento?

It worked only when I restart php(service php-fpm restart). is there any better solution to fix this issue?

---

The issue has been fixed when I add this;

apc_clear_cache() . "\n"; 
apc_clear_cache('user') . "\n";

apc_clear_cache('opcode') . "\n";

The cache problem occurred due to apc_cache. We can add above lines in some php file and call that file after each new change. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: make sure that the set theme is `enterprise/mytheme`. Also the tempalte for contact us page is `contacts/form.phtml`

Comment: Template is correct and  changes shows when I restart Php. I noticed this behaviour for all template changes and for custom modules we build. We are testing in our local magento where it works fine. But in server, we need to restart php to see  newly added changes in templates or module. Is this some issue with Nginx server?

Comment: I'm not sure but may be some caching system is used in your server. I guess you need to conform with your server guys to check that for ya.

Comment: I think the issue is with APC cache. I am checking this now.

Comment: did you try to use the "Flush Cache Storage" button (in system > manage cache)

Comment: The issue has been fixed when I add this;

apc_clear_cache() . "\n"; apc_clear_cache('user') . "\n";

apc_clear_cache('opcode') . "\n";

The cache problem occurred due to apc_cache. We can add above lines in some php file and call that file after each new change. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed when I add this;

apc_clear_cache() . "\n";
apc_clear_cache('user') . "\n";

apc_clear_cache('opcode') . "\n";

The cache problem occurred due to apc_cache. We can add above lines in some php file and call that file after each new change.